# How to format a highcharts .NET stacklabel total

Tags: .net, highcharts

I have a stacked chart with a total at the top of each stack which needs to display in millions. The documentation states the following for the Format/Formatter properties:

Callback JavaScript function to format the label. The value isgiven by this.total.

I have tried the following code:

```
YAxis = new List<YAxis>
            {
                new YAxis
                {
                    Min = 0,
                    Title = new YAxisTitle
                    {
                        Text = ""
                    },
                    StackLabels = new YAxisStackLabels
                    {
                        Enabled = true,
                        Style = new Hashtable() {{ "fontWeight", "bold" } },
                        Format = "${this.total:.1f}M"//,
                        //Formatter = "${this.total:.1f}M"
                    }
                }
            },
```

However the total is always displayed as $0.0M

Is this the correct syntax for accessing the total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it should be: `"${total:.1f}M"`

Comment: I thought I'd tried that but obviously not because it's working! Thanks for your help. I don't suppose you know if a calculation can be performed in the Format?

Comment: I'm glad it works! As for calculations, you should do them in the formatter function.